# BJT switch analsyis

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt

Can you double check my answer?

> Briefly explain the purpose of each diagram block:

[image]

Answer: This is basic BJT switch system, which will turn on when 5V supplied to their base but without knowing β I can not calculate write Rb or Rc. Also this circuit is missing the main load to turn on. Also wire from ground going across the 17v but not connecting.
GENSTO+ is 17VDC and D6 is 5v

Answer (score 0):

First, that's a rather poorly drawn schematic, so puts anything else the author says in question.

With 5 V at D6, there will be about 100 µA base current.  If the minimum guaranteed gain of the transistor is 50, for example, then this can support up to 5 mA collector current.  With 5 mA thru R6, it will drop 7.5 V.  Figure the saturation voltage of Q4 is about 200 mV at 5 mA.

So as long at GENSTO+ is from about 200 mV to 7.7 V, it will be switched between open when D6 is low, to pulled down to 200 mV with 1.5 kΩ in series when D6 is high.

Comment: No that all is in the question and GENSTO+ is 17VDC

Comment: @amir: Then you can work backwards to find the transistor gain required for it to saturate with D6 at 5 V.  There are transistors that do have that much guaranteed gain.